# Why execution stops and false is returned (Open Policy Agent, Rego)

Tags: opa, open-policy-agent, rego

I want to implement complex validation but I don't have enough knowledge.
This is how I imagine the rule to work in python:

```
input_data = {
    "attributes": {
        "request": {
            "http": {
                "headers": {
                    "claims": {
                        "realm_access": {
                            "roles": [
                                "[DATAFLOW] Delete Group",
                                "[CAPEX] Get All Kpis"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "DELETE",
                    "path": "/pets/dogs"
                }
            },
        },
        "parsed_path": [
            "api",
            "dataflow",
            "v100500",
            "groups",
            "123"
        ]
    }
}

data = {
        "endpoints": {
            "delete": {
                "[DATAFLOW] Delete Group": [
                    {
                        "parsed_path": [
                            "api",
                            "dataflow",
                            "v100500",
                            "groups"
                        ],
                        "path_length": 5,
                        "rule": "[DATAFLOW] Delete Group"
                    }
                ],
                "[DATAFLOW] Delete Source": [
                    {
                        "parsed_path": [
                            "api",
                            "dataflow",
                            "v3",
                            "sources",
                            "source"
                        ],
                        "path_length": 6,
                        "rule": "[DATAFLOW] Delete Source"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
}


def is_allowed():
    input_roles = input_data['attributes']['request']['http']['headers']['claims']['realm_access']['roles']
    input_method = input_data['attributes']['request']['http']['headers']['method'].lower()
    parsed_path = set(input_data['attributes']['parsed_path'])
    parsed_path_len = len(parsed_path)

    endpoints_by_rules = data['endpoints'][input_method]
    for input_role in input_roles:
        if input_role in endpoints_by_rules:
            rules = endpoints_by_rules[input_role]
            for rule in rules:
                rule_parsed_path = set(rule['parsed_path'])
                if parsed_path.intersection(rule_parsed_path) == rule_parsed_path \
                        and parsed_path_len == rule['path_length']:
                    return True
    return False

allow = True if is_allowed() else False
```

And here is what I was able to write, but this rule does not work correctly

```
package example

default allow = false

# Rule that checks access permission based on role and pathallow {
  is_allowed(input.attributes)
}

# Helper function to check access permission
is_allowed(attributes) {
  input_roles := attributes.request.http.headers.claims.realm_access.roles
  input_method := lower(attributes.request.http.headers.method)
  parsed_path := to_set(attributes.parsed_path)
  parsed_path_len := count(parsed_path)

  endpoints_by_rules := data.endpoints[input_method]

  # Checking that at least one user role has access
  some input_role
  input_role = input_roles[_]
  rules := endpoints_by_rules[input_role]

  # Checking that at least one rule for the current role allows access
  some rule
  rule = rules[_]
  rule_parsed_path := to_set(rule.parsed_path)

  # Checking that parsed_path contains all elements of rule_parsed_path
  rule_parsed_path & parsed_path == rule_parsed_path

  # Checking that the parsed_path length is equal to the path_length in the rule
  parsed_path_len == rule.path_length
}

# Helper function to convert list to set
to_set(l) = {x | x = l[_]}
```

Function execution stops at line with parsed_path
Is it possible to debug the rules? Tell me what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `data.endpoints` referred to in the policy provided during evaluation? If I cook one up, I can get your policy to evaluate to a result on the playground: https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/WNzXqB2NDT

Comment: Dear friend, you have no idea how much you helped me. How can I thank you?

Comment: The green check mark is thanks enough :)